# rmarkdown is not available (for R version 3.1.1)

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am looking to create some reports using R using markdown via RStudio. Unfortunately, I am unable to open  the scripting window as I am getting an error message when trying to download the 'rmarkdown' package.

Here is a list of what I have attempted to do to resolve the issue to date:

- Automatically install packages - all packages download properly except for one (rmarkdown) and I get the following errors:

> Installing package into `'C:/Users/rp5/Documents/R/win-library/3.1'` (as
>   'lib' is unspecified) `'C:\Program'` is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.

- If I try using `install.packages("rmarkdown")` or using the github manual downlaod:

> rmarkdown is not available (for R version 3.1.1)

- I have tried using various versions of R, updating my current packages, as well un-installing and reinstalling R and R Studio, deleting all previous packages.

Any ideas on what to try next?

Comment: `rmarkdown` is not available on CRAN.  Follow the instructions for installing at the rmarkdown page: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown

Answer (score 2):

`rmarkdown` package isn't available via CRAN now. You can install it with `devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")` command. Also `rmarkdown` package included in latest versions of the RStudio IDE.